# Can we raise an event from ViewModel to View?

Tags: c#, wpf

For example, my `ViewModel` do something. After that, I wanted to notify my `View` in order to do something that should only be done in `View`.

Something like;

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase{
  ...
  private void DoSomething(){
     //raise the event here and notify the View
  }
}
```

then in View;

```
public MyView(){
  InitializeComponent();
  ...
}

private void ViewModelSaidDoSomething(){
 //The View Model raises an event, do something here about it...
}
```

is that possible without breaking the MVVM concept?

Comment: Generally nothing wrong. If `DoSomething` was a public method, you could consider to use async/await instead of the event.

Comment: *"is that possible without breaking the MVVM concept?"* It's not only compatible with the MVVM concept, it's *exactly the right way* to do it.

Comment: If you use an event then you should use a weak event pattern. This is built in to the way bindings work. So you can use events but imo it's a bad choice. I'd prefer a dependency property and change handler in the view. Bind that to a property in the viewmodel. Change that property in the viewmodel and the view does whatever your event handling would do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Usually, what you can do is define the event from your `ViewModel`, then let your `View` subscribe from that event.

For example, in your ViewModel.

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase{
  ...
  //Define your event.
  public delegate void YourEventAction(string your_argument); 
  public event YourEventAction? YourEvent;
  
  private void DoSomething(){
     YourEvent?.Invoke(your_argument); //raise the event here, any subscriber will received this.
  }
}
```

Then you can subscribe for that event in your View.

```
public MyView(){
  InitializeComponent();
  ...
  DataContextChanged += ViewModelSaidDoSomething; //subscribe to DataContextChanged.
}

private void ViewModelSaidDoSomething(){ 
    var viewModel = (MyViewModel)DataContext; //Get your ViewModel from your DataContext.
    viewModel.YourEvent += (your_argument) =>{  //Subscribe to the event from your ViewModel.
        //The View Model raises an event, do something here about it...
    };
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Don't forget to unsubscribe from the old DataContext instance!!! (You would have to show the proper event handler signature, and also omit a lambda expression as handler)

Comment: There are a bunch of downsides to subscribing to an event. A potential memory leak. The view now needs to "know" about the viewmodel. When is this subscription to the handler added? When is it removed?what if the view is a usercontrol and "just" inherits the datacontext?

Comment: @Andy can you suggest a better approach in detail?

Comment: The only downside of subscribing to the event is if you don't care or don't know what happen next. Of course you can use `weak event pattern` to avoid a `potential` memory leak. The above example is the most basic and understandable implementation. Unsubscribing will be depends on the business logic of OP.

Answer (score 0):

My primary candidate for any viewmodel <-> view communication would be binding.
This is a weak event pattern, late binding and the view doesn't need to be aware of what type the viewmodel is. They went to a load of trouble to implement binding and it works well IMO.  Anyhow, binding means view and viewmodel are as loosely coupled as you can get whilst retaining reasonable practicality.

Here's an example.
The purpose is to allow a viewmodel to close a window.

The view functionality is encapsulated in a control.
Only code.

```
public class CloseMe : Control
{
    public bool? Yes
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool?)GetValue(YesProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(YesProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty YesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Yes",
                    typeof(bool?),
                    typeof(CloseMe),
                    new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(YesChanged)));
    private static void YesChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bool?)e.NewValue != true)
        {
            return;
        }
        CloseMe me = (CloseMe)d;
        Window parent = Window.GetWindow(me) as Window;
        parent.Close();
    }
}
```

Anywhere in a window or usercontrol goes in the window you want to close:

```
   <local:CloseMe Yes="{Binding CloseYes, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

That binds to a bool property CloseYes in the viewmodel.  Set that true and the window closes.

We can imagine encapsulating some data in a more complicated viewmodel object instead of just a boolean.  That would not be quite so elegant though.
A view isn't supposed to process data, so I'd question what you're doing if you're sending complex data.

Setting those doubts aside though.

If you wanted to transfer a complex type from A to B with loose coupling then the pub sub pattern is a good candidate.
The mvvm toolkit is my framework of preference and there's an implementation in there which you can use.  Messenger:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger

The message sent is an object you define and you can use WeakReferenceMessenger.  Which does what it implies and relies on a weak reference. Thus reducing the risk of memory leaks.
Other frameworks have similar mechanisms so you could take a look at what's in the one you prefer.

Comment: Interesting, this is very much appreciated!